# How to store the file path of an indexed document in Apache Solr 5.1.0

Tags: mysql, solr

I'm trying to store the file path of an locally stored indexed document in Apache Solr so I can then update the index with metadata that is stored in a DB in MySQL. That file path is how I'm going to relate the document to its corresponding metadata

I already have the filepath in the DB, I just need a way to store it when I index the documents. How can I store a documents file path in Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this information on a field `documentPath` for exemple and query the information on indexing. If you're using DataImportHandler just return the information on query and index it in the new field. Create the `documentPath` with string type for exemple.